# SQL Server, Tabular Model

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, ssas-tabular

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security_Policy 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE RLS.fn_CanSeeSalary(EmployeeName) 
ON dbo.Salary 
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

When I execute the query above I get the following error:

> Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
>   Unknown object type 'SECURITY' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
>   Incorrect syntax near 'FILTER'.

Comment: CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security_Policy
  ADD FILTER PREDICATE RLS.fn_CanSeeSalary(EmployeeName) 
    ON dbo.Salary
  WITH (STATE = ON);

Comment: yes bogdan sahlean

Comment: What's your SQL Version ? RLS is only available in SQL Server V12 and also SQL Server 2016 CTP

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB3194714) - 12.0.5203.0 (X64)   Sep 23 2016 18:13:56   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 15063: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: You need SQL Server 2016 for this to work. Since you have Evaluation Edition, I don't think upgrading it to the latest version will cause any troubles.

Comment: unable to connect sql server 2016 after installation,can't find the server instance name or the configuration file during the installation

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security_Policy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE RLS.fn_CanSeeSalary([EmployeeName]) 
ON dbo.Trn_AccDet
```

Comment: same error,  Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
Unknown object type 'SECURITY' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 44
Incorrect syntax near 'FILTER'.